# Exterior product and four vectors?

Tags: abstract-algebra, exterior-algebra, grassmannian

Quite a straight forward question but something I don't really understand. I have a mediocre grasp on the concept of exterior products in $3$ dimensions. However, is the product defined for two $4$-vectors?  If so how is it defined explicitly given two four vectors?

Comment: The exterior product (or wedge product) of any $k$ vectors in an $n$-dimensional vector space is always defined. (When $k>n$, the answer is $0$, but ...) The vector space of $2$-vectors (i.e., the exterior product of $2$ vectors) in $\Bbb R^4$ is $6$-dimensional.

Comment: @TedShifrin thanks for the info. I am quite confused though. Even slightly abstract concepts fry my brain as I am an applied ( albeit a young and struggling one )mathematician.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a coordinate description of the exterior product of two vectors in $\mathbb{R}^4$: if $e_i$ denotes the $i$th basis vector, then any $v \in \mathbb{R}^4$ has coordinates $(a^1,a^2 ,a^3,a^4)$, meaning that $v = \sum a^ie_i$. The defining characteristic of the exterior product is that it is bilinear and antisymmetric, so if $w = \sum b^i e_i$ is another vector we must have

$$v \wedge w = \sum_i a^ie_i \wedge \sum_j b^je_j = \sum_{i,j}a^ib^je_i\wedge e_j,$$

and since $e_i \wedge e_j = -e_j \wedge e_i$ this amounts to

$$v\wedge w = (a^1b^2 - a^2b^1)(e_1 \wedge e_2) + \cdots + (a^3b^4 - a^4b^3)(e^3 \wedge e^4)$$

as in Ted Shifrin's answer.

Comment: Do you know of any material which deals with exterior algebras for physics? My reason for asking is I would imagine any reference material would be written in hard language like in your answer and would steer clear of abstract ideas etc.

Answer (score 3):

Just as with the cross product of two vectors in $\Bbb R^3$, you want to compute things this way. Take the matrix whose columns are the two vectors $a$ and $b$:
$$\begin{bmatrix} a_1 & b_1 \\ a_2 & b_2 \\ a_3 & b_3 \\ a_4 & b_4 \end{bmatrix}.$$
Now compute its $\binom 42=6$ $2\times 2$ minors: 
\begin{align*}
x_{12} &= a_1b_2-a_2b_1 \\
x_{13} &= a_1b_3-a_3b_1 \\
x_{14} &= a_1b_4-a_4b_1 \\
x_{23} &= a_2b_3-a_3b_2 \\
x_{24} &= a_2b_4-a_4b_2 \\
x_{34} &= a_3b_4-a_4b_3.
\end{align*}
These are the standard coordinates of the $2$-vector $a\wedge b$.