# calculating the wedge product for 2 4D vectors

Tags: exterior-algebra, geometric-algebras

I can't understand whether the wedge product is supposed to generate a matrix, a vector, or even an area. it seems like every source I read says something different.

In one example, it seems that $v \wedge w = \text{the tensor of v and w} - \text{the tensor of w and v}$ which is supposed to product a matrix with zeros on the diagonal

In another example, roughly based on what I read, in trying to compute the wedge product between (2,3,4,5) and (6,7,8,9) they assume a standard basis and then calculate
$$
\begin{aligned}
 &\Bigl( 2(1,0,0,0) + 3(0,1,0,0) + 4(0,0,1,0) + 5(0,0,0,1)\Bigr) \\
\wedge &\Bigl(6(1,0,0,0) + 7(0,1,0,0) + 8(0,0,1,0) + 9(0,0,0,1)\Bigr).
\end{aligned}
$$
In their example, they did this with 3d so the output would be like $18(1,0,0) \wedge (0,1,0)$ would effectively give $18 \mathbf{k}$ if the coordinates were roughly represented as $(i,j,k)$. The problem is that when i try this technique for 2 4d vectors, I get stuff like $(1,0,0,0) \wedge (0,0,0,1)$ where reducing this to $\mathbf{i},\mathbf{j},\mathbf{k},\mathbf{l}$ doesn't make sense to me.

In the last example, the wedge product is supposed to be an orientated area of something like a bivector, so the result is supposed to be calculated as $\lVert u \rVert \lVert v \rVert \sin\theta$.

If someone would clarify whether the result of the wedge product is supposed to be a scalar area, a vector, or a matrix, it would help a lot. I'm thoroughly confused.

Thank you!

Comment: If you haven't already, check out the answers here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2350031/exterior-product-and-four-vectors

Comment: thx Jacob, that seems to confirm that the 2nd method of calculation as being the correct version.

Answer (score 4):

The wedge product is not a matrix, although a matrix representation of the coordinates with respect to a specific basis is possible.  The wedge product does have an area representation, but it is signed and oriented area that can be thought of as lying in the plane of the span of the wedge vectors.  Your numerical example can also be computed readily.  I'll attempt to answer some of these questions below in stages.  I will start off more generally, assuming that you might be interested in arbitrary general vector spaces (with a possibly non-Euclidean metric), and then for the numerical example, return to a Euclidean space.

## Coordinate expansion of a wedge product

Given a basis for a non-Euclidean N-dimensional vector space $ \left\{ {f_\mu} \right\} $, and it's reciprocal basis $ \left\{ {f^\mu} \right\} $ where $ f_\mu \cdot f^\nu = {\delta_\mu}^\nu $, the decomposition of a vector in this space along each of the basis directions has the form (sums implied)
$$x = \left( { x \cdot f^\mu } \right) f_\mu.$$
Observe that $ x \cdot f^\mu $ are the coordinates of the vector $ x $ with respect to the basis $ \left\{ {f_\mu} \right\} $.  A visualization of such a decomposition with respect to a pair of vectors is illustrated in fig. 1.1.
[image: Resolution of a vector with respect to a pair of basis vectors.]

Writing
$$y = \left( { y \cdot f^\mu } \right) f_\mu,$$
let's expand the wedge product $ x \wedge y $ in terms their coordinates for this specific basis.  We have
$$\begin{aligned}x \wedge y&=\left( { \left( { x \cdot f^\mu } \right) f_\mu } \right) \wedge\left( { \left( { y \cdot f^\nu } \right) f_\nu } \right) \\ &=\left( { x \cdot f^\mu } \right)\left( { y \cdot f^\nu } \right)\left( {f_\mu \wedge f_\nu} \right) \\ &=\sum_{\mu \ne \nu}\left( { x \cdot f^\mu } \right)\left( { y \cdot f^\nu } \right)\left( {f_\mu \wedge f_\nu} \right) \\ &=\sum_{\mu < \nu}\left( { x \cdot f^\mu } \right)\left( { y \cdot f^\nu } \right)\left( {f_\mu \wedge f_\nu} \right)+\sum_{\nu > \mu}\left( { x \cdot f^\nu } \right)\left( { y \cdot f^\mu } \right)\left( {f_\nu \wedge f_\mu} \right) \\ &=\sum_{\mu < \nu}\left( {\left( { x \cdot f^\mu } \right)\left( { y \cdot f^\nu } \right)-\left( { y \cdot f^\mu } \right)\left( { x \cdot f^\nu } \right)} \right)\left( {f_\mu \wedge f_\nu} \right),\end{aligned}$$
where we have used the fact that $ f_\mu \wedge f_\mu = 0 $, for any $ \mu $, have performed a dummy index swap in the second sum, and finally, used the antisymmetry property $ f_\nu \wedge f_\mu = - f_\mu \wedge f_\nu $ to group terms.  We see that the coordinates of each of the basis bivectors has a determinant structure
$$   x \wedge y =\sum_{\mu < \nu}\begin{vmatrix}   x \cdot f^\mu  & x \cdot f^\nu  \\    y \cdot f^\mu  & y \cdot f^\nu\end{vmatrix}f_\mu \wedge f_\nu.$$

## Area interpretation of the wedge product

We may reduce this sum to its simplest form by introducing an orthonormal "standard" basis $ \left\{ {e_1, e_2} \right\} $ for the subspace containing the span of $ x, y $  such that $ x $ is colinear with $ e_1 $.  That is
$$\begin{aligned}   x &= \left( { x \cdot e^1 } \right) e_1 \\    y &=   \left( { y \cdot e^1 } \right) e_1 +   \left( { y \cdot e^2 } \right) e_2.\end{aligned}$$
Given that we are allowing the underlying vector space to be non-Euclidean, by "orthonormal" here, we mean $ e_\mu \cdot e_\mu = \pm 1$, for $ \mu \in \left\{ {1,2} \right\} $, and $ e_1 \cdot e_2 = 0 $.  In terms of this basis, the wedge of the two vectors expands to
$$   x \wedge y =\begin{vmatrix}   x \cdot e^1  & 0            \\    y \cdot e^1  & y \cdot e^2\end{vmatrix}e_1 \wedge e_2.$$
We see that such a basis choice "diagonalizes" the determinant coefficient of the one remaining wedge product basis bivector, leaving just
$$   x \wedge y =\left( { x \cdot e^1 } \right)\left( { y \cdot e^2 } \right)e_1 \wedge e_2.$$
If we form a parallelogram by placing $ y $ at the head of $ x $ and then complete a loop back along $ -x $ and $ -y $, as
illustrated in fig. 1.2, we see that
$ x \cdot e^1 $ is the length of the base of the parallelogram, and $ y \cdot e^2 $ is the length of the projection of $ y $ along the perpendicular to $ x $.
[image: Parallelogram area]

In the example above the wedge product's numerical coefficient is positive, but if we had computed $ y \wedge x $, as illustrated in fig. 1.3, the base vector is now $ -x \cdot e^1 e_1 $, so
$$   y \wedge x =\left( { -x \cdot e^1 } \right)\left( { y \cdot e^2 } \right)e_1 \wedge e_2=   - (x \wedge y),$$
as required algebraically, so we say that $ x \wedge y $ is a signed area with respect to the orientation of the basic $ \left\{ { e_1, e_2 } \right\} $.  In particular, if the wedge is positive, it has the same orientation as the square formed by applying this parallelogram construction recipe to the vectors $ e_1, e_2 $ as illustrated in fig. 1.4.
[image: y wedge x]
[image: e_1 wedge e_2]

Observe that the wedge product's signed area interpretation is also basis dependent.  For example, had we selected $ f_1 = -e_1, f_2 = e_2 $ as our basis vectors, then the numerical coefficient $ \left( { x \cdot f^1 } \right) \left( { y \cdot f^2 } \right) $ would flip sign accordingly, and we would say that $ x \wedge y $ has a negative sign with respect to the bivector $ f_1 \wedge f_2 $.

## The numerical example from the original question

With $\mathbf{a} = \mathbf{i} + 3 \mathbf{j} + 4 \mathbf{k} + 5 \mathbf{l}$ and $\mathbf{b} = 6 \mathbf{i} + 7 \mathbf{j} + 8 \mathbf{k} + 9 \mathbf{l}$, we have
$$\begin{aligned}B &= \mathbf{a} \wedge \mathbf{b} \\ &= \left( {2 \mathbf{i} + 3 \mathbf{j} + 4 \mathbf{k} + 5 \mathbf{l}} \right) \wedge \left( { 6 \mathbf{i} + 7 \mathbf{j} + 8 \mathbf{k} + 9 \mathbf{l} } \right) \\ &=14 \mathbf{i} \wedge \mathbf{j} + 16 \mathbf{i} \wedge \mathbf{k} + 18 \mathbf{i} \wedge \mathbf{l} \\ &\quad+18 \mathbf{j} \wedge \mathbf{i} + 24 \mathbf{j} \wedge \mathbf{k} + 27 \mathbf{j} \wedge \mathbf{l} \\ &\quad+24 \mathbf{k} \wedge \mathbf{i} + 28 \mathbf{k} \wedge \mathbf{j} + 36 \mathbf{k} \wedge \mathbf{l}  \\ &\quad+30 \mathbf{l} \wedge \mathbf{i} + 35 \mathbf{l} \wedge \mathbf{j} + 40 \mathbf{l} \wedge \mathbf{k}  \\ &=(14 -18) \mathbf{i} \wedge \mathbf{j}+ (16-24) \mathbf{i} \wedge \mathbf{k}+ (18-30) \mathbf{i} \wedge \mathbf{l}+ (24-28) \mathbf{j} \wedge \mathbf{k}+ (27-35) \mathbf{j} \wedge \mathbf{l}+ (36-40) \mathbf{k} \wedge \mathbf{l} \\ &=4 \mathbf{j} \wedge \mathbf{i} + 8 \mathbf{k} \wedge \mathbf{i} + 12 \mathbf{l} \wedge \mathbf{i} + 4 \mathbf{k} \wedge \mathbf{j} + 8 \mathbf{l} \wedge \mathbf{j} + 4 \mathbf{l} \wedge \mathbf{k} \\
&= \left( { 8 \sqrt{5} } \right)\frac{\mathbf{j} \wedge \mathbf{i} + 2 \mathbf{k} \wedge \mathbf{i} + 3 \mathbf{l} \wedge \mathbf{i} + \mathbf{k} \wedge \mathbf{j} + 2 \mathbf{l} \wedge \mathbf{j} + \mathbf{l} \wedge \mathbf{k}}{2 \sqrt{5} }.\end{aligned}$$

In the last step, the wedge product has been factored into a scalar part $\sqrt{320} = 8 \sqrt{5}$ and a unit bivector part (assuming a Euclidean metric.)
The scalar factor is the area, and the unit bivector (i.e. squares to $\pm 1$) provides the orientation.

To confirm that the bivector on the right is a unit bivector, one can compute the (geometric algebra) square of the numerator:
$$\left( { \mathbf{j} \wedge \mathbf{i} + 2 \mathbf{k} \wedge \mathbf{i} + 3 \mathbf{l} \wedge \mathbf{i} + \mathbf{k} \wedge \mathbf{j} + 2 \mathbf{l} \wedge \mathbf{j} + \mathbf{l} \wedge \mathbf{k} } \right)^2= -1 -4 -9 -1 -4 -1 = -20 = -\left( { 2 \sqrt{5} } \right)^2.$$

Now, does an area of $ \sqrt{320} $ make sense?  We can compute that area using standard vector algebra methods to confirm that this is the case.  First use Gram-Schmidt to compute the portion of $ \mathbf{b} $ that is perpendicular to $ \mathbf{a} $, which is:
$$\mathbf{b}_\perp = \mathbf{b} - \left( { \mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{b} } \right) \frac{\mathbf{a}}{\mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{a}} = (52/27) \mathbf{i} + (8/9) \mathbf{j} -(4/27) \mathbf{k} -(32/27) \mathbf{l}.$$
Using this, we can compute the (squared) area (with $\mathbf{x}^2 \equiv \mathbf{x} \cdot \mathbf{x}$), to find
$$\mathbf{a}^2 \mathbf{b}_\perp^2 = 320,$$
as expected.

You also saw that the wedge product magnitude should have the form
$$\left\lVert {\mathbf{a}} \right\rVert\left\lVert {\mathbf{b}} \right\rVert \sin\theta.$$
That is easy to show, first calculating
$$\cos\theta = \frac{ \mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{b} }{ \left\lVert {\mathbf{a}} \right\rVert \left\lVert {\mathbf{b}} \right\rVert },$$
after which we find
$$\left\lVert {\mathbf{a}} \right\rVert \left\lVert {\mathbf{b}} \right\rVert \sin\theta = 8 \sqrt{5},$$
as seen above.

You stated that $(18 \mathbf{i}) \wedge \mathbf{j}$ "would effectively give" $18 \mathbf{k}$.  That is not correct.  All that you can say is:
$$
\left(18 \mathbf{i}\right) \wedge \mathbf{j} = 
18 \left( \mathbf{i} \wedge \mathbf{j} \right).
$$
However, in 3D, it is true that $\mathbf{i} \wedge \mathbf{j}$ is dual to $\mathbf{k}$, but the wedge product is a bivector, not a vector (the fact that the wedge of two vectors has the same numerical coefficients as the cross product of those vectors helps lead to that confusion).  It is a different beast.  This duality may be represented in various ways.  In geometric algebra, for example, this duality can be observed by multiplying by the $\mathbb{R}^3$ pseudoscalar $I = \mathbf{i} \mathbf{j} \mathbf{k}$, for example:

$$\begin{aligned}I \mathbf{k}&=\mathbf{i} \mathbf{j} \mathbf{k} \mathbf{k} \\ &=\mathbf{i} \mathbf{j}  \\ &=\mathbf{i} \wedge \mathbf{j},\end{aligned}$$

and
$$   \mathbf{x} \wedge \mathbf{y} = I \left( { \mathbf{x} \times \mathbf{y} } \right).$$

(this is one way to extract the $\sin\theta$ representation of the wedge product$)

There are other representations of the duality operation that do not require geometric algebra, such as the hodge dual from differential forms, but the end effect is the same, providing a way of mapping a k-form to a N-k form.  In general, such duals have to be treated as different algebraic objects.

Comment: What does the wedge product between i and j actually mean though? OP asked (and I am confused about how) to calculate the wedge product between two vectors, and now we're left with an answer in terms of a wedge product between two vectors.

Comment: @John, I have attempted to expand my answer to address more of the OPs questions (and yours.)